# Can only logged in users access the Google Firestore Cloud datastore what about websites

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I learn Firestore and have beginner question.
If I have a web site that connect to Google Firestore Cloud datastore and the website is pulling documents from the Cloud datastore like `name: value` json struktur.

Is then the website a "user" or I mean do the website need to sign in even it has apikey?
I read [Get started with Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) and can only see settings that need a signed in user!

I want a website to pull this `name: value` from Cloud datastore that all I want?

Here is the rules:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /<some_path>/ {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;;
    }
  }
}
```

looks like I must make some Auth for a user not a website?
Please advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that one must be signed in to be able to secure Firestore databas and if a website dont want to force users to sign in the website can sign in(under the hood)
anonymous and if the user decide to sign in later the anonymous account then with the help of `linkWithCredential` transformeds to the users own account like Google or Facebook sign in.

> You can use Firebase Authentication to create and use temporary
> anonymous accounts to authenticate with Firebase. These temporary
> anonymous accounts can be used to allow users who haven't yet signed
> up to your app to work with data protected by security rules. If an
> anonymous user decides to sign up to your app, you can link their
> sign-in credentials to the anonymous account so that they can continue
> to work with their protected data in future sessions.

[Authenticate with Firebase Anonymously Using JavaScript](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth)

Answer (score 1):

With your security rules, a user that accesses Cloud Firestore directly from the client-side code using one of the Firebase SDKs, will have to be signed in to Firebase Authentication. This applies no matter whether the client is a native mobile app, or a web site.

If you have server-side code that accesses the same Firestore database using either one of its Admin SDKs or its REST API passing administrative credentials, that code actually bypasses these security rules - so is not bound by its requirement to be signed into Firebase Authentication.

So if you render the web site server-side and read from the database in that same server-side code, there is no need for the client-side user/code to be signed in to Firebase Authentication. But if the client-side code is directly accessing Firestore using one of its SDKs or its RET API, the user will need to be signed into Firebase Authentication.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand Thanks when I set it to `false` like his `allow read, write: if false;` then I cant access the [Cloud Firestore db](https://snipboard.io/9hlrQn.jpg). I'm using the basic Todo example for [React redux-firestore](https://github.com/prescottprue/redux-firestore). How did you mean by "that code actually bypasses these security rules"

Comment: If the `if false` blocks, then you're accessing the database using a client-side SDK. I tried to cover all cases, since your question is missing a lot of information. In that case if reading data works when you set the results to `if request.auth != null`, that means that a user is signed into the site on their browser.

Comment: Thanks but I have no Users it's just my ReactJs app using NPM dependencies `"firebase": "^7.2.3",` and `"redux-firestore"`

Comment: If I set like `allow read, write: if false;` or `allow read, write: if request.auth != null` then I get the "FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions" From my ReactJs app. Look like only way to access is with `allow read, write: if true;`  . What am I missing and is this not a bad idea to have "true"

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to efficiently help here. But indeed, setting `if true` is usually a bad idea for security, and you'll need to sign the user in to your web site to then use their identity to ensure they only can access data they're authorized for. I'd recommend reading: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules

Comment: Thanks I have read the rules link looks like I cant use Firestore database. My ReactJs app website is a foto gallery only no need to make users sign in. I need a backend to store json structure data only

Comment: I answered my own question please comment if needed